# provide documentation to clarify @user-syntax-denied in comments

Tags: feature-request, display-names

I just tried posting a comment with the `@user` syntax two or three times in the middle of the comment as an illustrative literal string, and I got "denied": a popup box showed up with

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified

and it bumped me back to editing my comment. I had to figure out that I could escape it with ` backtick  literal syntax and that wouldn't cause the comment-denied behavior.

(This behavior has already been mentioned in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99106/posting-a-second-lert)

In this popup box, could you please add a link to the [help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)? Otherwise the message is not very helpful, and could be clarified. *I* understood it, but only because I've been participating in the `@user`-feud, and only after I read through my comment a few times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tell the user who will be notified of a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate! I'm not trying to complain about the behavior (at least not directly), I'm trying to state that there should be a way to steer users toward an explanation of what is going on.

Comment: ...and it's also different behavior: the past discussion has been about the `@user` part of the comments being removed. This is behavior that prevents the comment from being posted.

Comment: Did you check the question I actually suggested? It's not a complaint, either, and **it reads a *lot* less like a rant**, which I think is quite productive for the cause. Beyond that, this information already is available--click the "help" link next to each comment. The only thing you're not told is about the backtick trick, which seems reasonable considering that it is a trick. It won't actually notify the second person, it just allows you to post the comment anyway.

Comment: Duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99106/posting-a-second-lert

Comment: @Cody -- ok, you have a point about the tone. And yes, I did check that question.

Comment: @Neal -- my point is to ask for documentation, not to complain about the behavior. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Cody -- TJ Crowder just pointed out, as you did that this is already in the "help" link. That's fair, but when you get a confusing message that pops up and stops you from doing something, there should be a link to that documentation as well.