# Which Tomalak is being noticed about @Tomalak comment?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

There are two Tomalaks. Which one is being noticed about my @comment? Both of them? Or which one?

[image]

Comment: First one climbing back up

Comment: @random -- why close this?

Comment: This is an excellent example of why [this feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment) would be very useful.

Comment: This question is answered pointedly in the fourth mark on the FAQ of how comment replies work @nea

Comment: @Tibbits: I know, that's probably why I asked this question.

Comment: @random -- can you **please** explain why you do that with the @ tag?

Comment: @random: If I get it, the late commenter will get noticed?

Comment: Correct, the last person in the stream with the first match will be notified. It reads back up the hole.

Comment: Hah, I never noticed this question before. Oh, the fame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one that commented would be notified if i understand correctly from the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

Comment: I'll accept your question as fast as StackOverflow allows it

Comment: @genesis stated another way, the *closest* one to your comment will be notified.