# Commenting bug when commenting to a particular person

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)

Whenever I try to start a comment (either new comment or editing existing) with:

> @Robert: blah blah blah

and then save my comment all it ends up is:

> blah blah blah

User reference is just simply gone... Has anything been changed that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Goodness, yes... This has changed recently ([documented here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)) and then people have [come out of the woodwork](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment) opposing it. Sort questions by most-recent to see that ~50% of the recent posts on Meta concern this behavior.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate, yes. Thanks guys. You can vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there has been a change. When you reply to the post owner, the @xyz is automatically stripped. Many users have [strongly objected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97283/134300) to this change, but at the moment it looks like it's here to stay.

Comment: Definitely here to stay. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment) is really the only proposal that has a hope, in part because it doesn't adversely affect the signal-to-noise ratio on the site as a whole, and in part because it's *constructively presented*.

Comment: Ok thanks. I wasn't aware of this change. And it seems unreasonable since comments have double-faceted functionality which is confusing.

Comment: @Robert: The idea is that they don't have two purposes. Using @ to notify the **post owner** is superfluous, since the post owner will *always* be notified of any comments to their posts. This is documented in the help text you see when typing a comment--click the "help" link to the next of the comment entry box for details. (Or read any of Jeff Atwood's numerous posts explaining the behavior.)

Comment: @Cody: User referencing isn't just for notifications but also **a lot for human readability**. And this fact has been overlooked here. It's not all in computers but in the eyes of the beholder.