# Warning for wrong @name in comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

Sometimes (quite often) persons write the wrong @name in a comment. For example, in [Generic T get type from class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371746/generic-t-get-type-from-class) Preet Sangha tried to reply me in a comment to the question, but addressed the comment to @xantos instead of @xanatos. Would it be possible to issue a warning when you write a comment that won't notify anyone in the page? (I know there are some rules for matching usernames.)

Comment: Very much related: [Tell the user who will be notified of a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99261).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tell the user who will be notified of a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment)

Comment: The other suggestion doesn't seem to directly cover wrongly typed @name. If one speed-write the comment, it could miss it.

Comment: The matching algorithm uses the first three letters of the name, by design.  So your "incorrect" example would still match.

Comment: @Robertt: **No, that's not correct.** See the last sentence in #3 of [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019). (And I can't submit this comment without a backtick, isn't that crazy `:-)`)

Comment: @Robert: Ping!!

Comment: Only now I see that Robert provided an excellent argument why xanatos has a good point here `:-)`

Comment: @Robert I **know** I didn't receive the comment in the inbox. Had I received the comment, I wouldn't have done this question on meta. Ah... Now I comprehend what Hendrik did :-) :-)

Comment: @Hendrik: Aw, hell.  You really expect me to read [all that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) :/  OK, this gets an upvote from me.

Comment: @Robert: No, I don't `:-)` Just wanted to point you to the standard reference that has become almost unreadable indeed.