# Is the @reply in a comment to the editor of a post broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, comment-replies

According to Jeff's answer, [@replies to post editors are implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him/36055#36055):

> So you can now @reply to editors of a post even if they haven't
> commented.

Yet, I just tried to address the editor of a question in a comment and couldn't. No auto-completion of the name. I typed it in anyway, but it doesn't seem to have reached the editor. I tried it at another post where the same user *commented* and the @reply worked as expected there (auto-completion and everything).

Happened with this question:
[SQL query issue (with screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8146618/939860)

I haven't changed anything further so I wouldn't contaminate the crime scene.

#### Edit:

I ran some tests with OMG_Ponies, and he did get the messages. So, it's only the auto-complete that doesn't work as expected. And the `_` in his name helped to fool me at first.

Comment: @yoda: It's clear by now that you should get this. But for science!

Comment: Yes, that was never in doubt. Was just checking to see if it was broken, but it isn't :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's that it's not broken, it's just not implemented as part of the comment autocomplete.

While there is a [related request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106534/expand-the-username-auto-completion-to-everyone-who-can-be-notified) to get that working, as I noted in my answer there the current feeling is that adding the list of editors to the autocomplete would introduce [unnecessary complexity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment/106733#comment-274143). `@reply`ing to an editor without the assistance of the autocomplete will still work, however.

In your particular case, your original comment referenced `@omg_ponies` which isn't a valid match for that user's name (the underscore cannot be used as a replacement for the space), so no notification would have been generated.

Comment: Yeah, the '_' in combination with the missing auto-complete had me fooled. I amended my answer with the result of additional tests.

Answer (score 11):

No, replying works – just the autocompletion doesn't. The autocompleter only autocompletes actual commentors. We decided to *not* autocomplete editors, because

a) it's a *very* rarely used feature, 
 b) it'd be quite some work to make this work nice performance-wise, and 
c) it would probably be more confusing then helpful ("Who the hell is this User12345 and why is he in my autocomplete list?").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand your point, though I am not sure I agree. There are usually only one or two editors involved or a hand full at most. Anyway, it did confuse me. An addition to the faq might help. Or maybe this post will. Would have helped me if I had found it ..