# Gaming the edit system with tiny edits?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, review-abuse, serial-edits

I was on the Suggested Edit's review tab today, and noticed that this user (take a look at today's [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073358/skami?tab=reputation)), was putting in hundreds of edits adding the C# tag to questions that didn't really need it. He got over 275 reputation today.

To me, this looked like spamming the edit system to get reputation. I started rejecting them as too minor, with also a custom message telling him this.

- Here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1367475
- Another: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1367446
- Another: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1367446

And about 20-30 more. I hit my review cap for the day.

Is this valid editing behavior, and, if not, would a mod please get involved?

UPDATE: I've seen a couple of other meta questions about this in the last day, but it looks like the spike in gaming the system is passed.

Comment: Yeah, I've been rejecting these as much as possible. This is an abuse, no doubt.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks. Me too. We need to get a mod on this problem.

Comment: I've now started rejecting any and all edits of his that I can find. This is not acceptable editing behaviour. He'll be auto-blocked from suggesting more edits soon if we can reject enough of his edits.

Comment: Sigh, it's depressing to see how many got approved anyway. In any case, it seems his editing tempo has been halted. No new edits for 2 minutes now, and a moderator has been vetoing edits too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know. Something like a hundred.

Comment: I have seen these single tag edit suggestion a lot. And reject all of them.  Some days Iá a serial rejecter...

Comment: he also got 100 Reputation as Association Bonus, but 188 Reputation from adding a tag is still too much

Comment: @Dirty-flow: Exactly. Way too much. We need a mod!

Comment: Sigh... we shouldn't really need a mod. We need the community to shape up and start rejecting.

Comment: @Bart: I'd be out there rejecting with you, but I used up all my approve/rejects for the day.

Comment: @Linuxios - I suspect that so has Bart and Gamecat (as have I).

Comment: @Oded: Hm. Is he still submitting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1073358/skami?tab=activity Doesn't look like it, not for 11 minutes now (toilet break?)

Comment: @Oded: Well, maybe he learned his lesson? I hope...

Comment: @Linuxios: Most likely he ran into the auto-suggested-edit-ban. No edit suggestions will be accepted for 7 days. A moderator got in on him to, vetoing the edits and speeding up the process.

Comment: @Linuxios It depends.  If he knew they were inappropriate edits and did them anyway, he'll have been encouraged by the fact that quite a few were approved.  If he honestly thought he was helping, he will hopefully have learned that he wasn't, and may end up just not suggesting edits, or may end up performing better suggested edits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Good. Then we don't have to worry (for 7 days at least).

Comment: @Servy: I think they were malicious. Do you really think he though adding the C# tag was improving the world to questions where it was obviously inferred?

Comment: @Bart: I don't like you anymore.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Not you, other moderators. Never you. We like you......

Comment: @Linuxios It's rather common to see people who make serial minor edits.  Usually they find some problem that they can put into a search query and apply a quick change to everything returned (as an example, I've seen people that search for misspelled works, or search for things like "solved" in titles just to remove them).  Out of those that I've spoken to on it, most sincerely thought they were helping by submitting dozens of such edits, and since they are usually approved (en mass) at first, it only encourages them further and gives the impression it's an appropriate edit.

Comment: @Servy: I guess. Either way, it comes across as gaming the rep system. If he had edit privileges, it would be different, but I guess it probably wasn't malicious.

Comment: related: [An alert to serial minor edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits)

Comment: can we go back to Wikipedia's system of editing? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152782/166277

Comment: @prusswan: What do you mean?

Comment: Downvoter? Explanation?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it would help searching through all the XNA questions by adding the language the person that asked the question was looking for. I wasn't trying to pull of anything malicious. I myself was getting somewhat annoyed when searching through the XNA questions and running into answers that I wasn't looking mainly cause of the tags and like Servy stated since most were approved it didn't occur to me that I was doing any harm to the community. Like I said to Linuxios I will read the rules more thoroughly before making such (massive) changes.

Comment: @Skami: Thank you! Nice to know that there was no malice behind it. Sorry if this post sounds a little derogatory -- just ment to stop something that happened to be against the rules. I get what you were going for, we just want you to fix the other problems with a post too when you edit it. Good luck on SO!

Comment: This whole question is blatantly obsolete and should be ***deleted***. See for example [Get rid of the "too minor" reject reason entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039) and ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253326).
I don't see any justification what so ever for keeping this question around. Doing so is very confusing and obfuscating - to say the very least.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you try @-ing the user? I came across someone today who (it became clear as I went through the queue) had searched for a mispelling of a C++ header file. The user then fixed this mispelling in titles and bodies, but ignored the myriad other issues in posts. The first time I rejected one as Too Minor it had already been accepted. Sigh. See my many other posts on this such as [The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits) or my examples of horrible approved edits in [Why no honeypot suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159544/why-no-honeypot-suggested-edits/159573#159573) but anyway. I went to the post, fixed all the other things (typos, grammar, code snippets without backticks, thanks in advance) and added an @ comment aimed at the editor saying

> if you are going to suggest edits to a question please fix everything not just the typo in the title. Take a look at the revisions to see what else needed to be fixed on this post

Then I went back to the queue and continued to reject "too minor" edits of the same typo by this same user. But within minutes, the editor @-ed me saying "ok" and presumably has learned how the system works a little better. I think being able @ editors is a terrific feature and I encourage good reviewers to use it on robo-approved bad edits. There is more than one way to teach people how to do things.

Comment: How do you @ an editor, besides going to one of their questions and posing an off topic comment?

Comment: You go to the post they edited and comment on it specifically. It might not appear to work (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112360/is-the-reply-in-a-comment-to-the-editor-of-a-post-broken ) but it does

Comment: And how do they notice it, if they never go to that question again? Or does it actually notify them? (+1 :))

Comment: It notifies them I'm sure, since my editor came and replied to me so quickly.

Comment: @Linuxios You can @ reply anyone who edited the post you're commenting on, you just don't get autocompletion when typing the comment.  They will still get a notification.