# Reputation and number of edits when a tag expires

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-wiki

Let say: there is a tag, which is not very popular and there are only few questions using it. If I edit its tag-wiki, I'm gonna gain 2 reputation and the number of edits (for the "Research Assistant"-badge) is gonna increase. But what will happen, when the tag expires after six months? Will I lose the reputation? Will the number of edits for the badge decrease?

Comment: Does 2 reputation really matter that much?

Comment: Many a mickle makes a muckle

Comment: What? What does that mean?

Comment: 2 reputation for a single edit is not much, but if you make 100 edits, you will earn 200 reputation. And for me 200 reputation does matter

Comment: @Linuxios http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/many_a_mickle_makes_a_muckle

Comment: And if you're trying to get reputation from editing, you're using the site wrong.

Comment: @Linuxios No, the system gives reputation for approved edits for a reason.

Comment: @EliahKagan: I know. But if you really want reputation, how about you answer things instead?

Comment: @Linuxios Good edits are fundamentally useful. You could take your reasoning a step further and say that users who want to earn reputation shouldn't answer non-bountied questions.

Comment: @EliahKagan: That's not my argument. My argument is to edit for the sake of editing, not for the sake of 2 rep. Answer for the sake of answering. Rep can be your priority, but still do for the sake of doing.

Comment: @Linuxios are you thinking I'm doing something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/gaming-the-edit-system-with-tiny-edits). Creating tag wikis for new tags is very useful, and nobody knows if the tag will have enough question

Comment: Dirty-flow: I agree that tag wikis are useful. I just disagree that worrying about the 2 rep is worth the time that could be spent making contributions to the site.