# How does @comment work for authors of edit to my post which I've rejected or are still pending?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I've just found out that you can @comment to the author of a successful edit to your post. That's excellent.

From time to time I will reject an edit and would like to thank the editor, but let them know why their suggestions were rejected.

While @comment for accepted edits doesn't autocomplete and so it looks like it won't reach the editor, but it will. What is the behavior for the authors of the following?

1. pending edits
2. rejected edits

---

- [Allow post editor to see @comments directed at him](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36052/303080)
- [Is the @reply in a comment to the editor of a post broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112360/303080)

Comment: That's what the rejection reason is for. The last option allows you to enter custom text.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog are you sure the author receives a notification of that? I was under the impression that that feature is a dead-end; the text goes nowhere. Am I wrong?

Comment: According to the FAQ on this topic, [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), the subset of users you can notify "does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions".

Comment: No; it's shown in the suggested edit review, which the author of the suggested edit sees.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog "Any user who has edited the post (does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions)." So this means that *for sure* they are not notified?

Comment: Yes, for sure, unless they commented.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog your first [commen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318702/how-does-comment-work-for-authors-of-edit-to-my-post-which-ive-rejected-or-are#comment1044797_318702)t still confuses me as it would not be available to the editor. That's not what the rejection reason "is for".

Comment: The editor is definitely able to see the review task and the rejection reason.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog okay I was told otherwise, I'll look into that separately.  **edit:** Oh, they wouldn't receive a notification, but they could see it if they went back to the question?