# Include closing moderators and editors in comment @reply autocomplete list

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expand the username auto-completion to everyone who can be notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106534/expand-the-username-auto-completion-to-everyone-who-can-be-notified)

[According to the Meta FAQ question about @replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work):

> You can explicitly notify one (1) other commenter, **editor, or ♦ moderator who closed a question.**

I was actually unaware that it was possible to ping a moderator who had closed a question, and I think part of the reason I assumed this was not possible is because a closing moderator doesn't appear in the comment's autocomplete suggestions. Similarly, editors do not appear in the autocomplete list, though they are also able to be pinged in a comment.

Would it be possible to include these names in the @reply autocomplete list since they are in fact pingable?

Comment: FYI: Editors aren't autocompleted either.

Comment: @Shog9: I didn't even notice that. I'll add that to this request, too. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm pretty ambivalent about this request, tending towards negative. I'd say 90% of the time that I see the OP addressing closers, it's along the lines of "You guys are poo-poo heads!", and I don't really think making it easier for them to actually _notify_ is a good idea. If the OP (or anyone else, really) needs to get in touch with the mods, a flag seems like a fine way to do it. Adding this **just for editors** makes a _bit_ more sense to me.

Comment: @TimStone: Thanks, I think my searches must have been phrased too narrowly to find that question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I'd honestly just like to see it for consistency's sake. It's somewhat jarring UX to me that there are users who are able to be notified but don't appear in the autocomplete. Is that a compelling enough reason to add it? I don't know, and everyone may not agree, but I would personally answer "yes". I won't expound much beyond that, though, since this appears to be a duplicate of a previous proposal anyhow.

Comment: I certainly understand your desire for consistency -- it definitely _makes sense_ that these names should be in the list. I just think there are slightly more compelling reasons that they not be. :)

Comment: Think of it like a hidden feature. There's no good reason for this to be exposed in the UI. I don't want everyone whose question I close or edit to be able to contact me *even more easily*. Sheesh, I'd just stop doing it. Not worth the pain in the neck.