# Please allow non-Unicode named editors be pinged with autocomplete

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies, unicode, autocomplete

Currently, you can @reply to any person with the auto complete. Normally, you type the first letter of their name then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to finish it.

Unicode names work differently, you don't have to start the name (thankfully):

[image]

And just press tab to complete it.

Can the same behaviour be added to pinging *editors*? Currently there is no auto-complete for *editors*, so could there be an exception for Unicode named editors?

Comment: wait... is that what you see my name as!?

Comment: will do but seriously: do you see the first letter of my name like a horzontal `S`?? Not: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wcCIA.png??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yes, but I think it must have changed at some point because people used to call you shob... Is it meant to be `S` not `ᔕ`?

Comment: it should be as in the image in my previous comment... I used to be called `shub` <-- pretty plain tho!

Comment: "An exception for Unicode-named editors" seems kind of silly. If anything, we would just [add all editors to the auto-complete menu](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106534/expand-the-username-auto-completion-to-everyone-who-can-be-notified). Explicitly checking to see if they have Unicode characters in their name would not be worthwhile.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure. Just saying that if we have to go in and check the editors list anyways, it doesn't make sense to run a *second* check to look for names with Unicode characters versus just including all of them.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I see the same character as Tim and this is consistent with other rendering of the character for [ʃa] I see on the web, e.g. the [BJCreeUNI font](http://www.naskapi.ca/nk/Install-Syllabics) and [a Wikipedia picture of Ojibwe syllabics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ojibwe_writing_systems#Ojibwe_syllabics). These fonts are indeed inconsistent with [the Unicode reference glyph](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1400.pdf). Maybe there are typographical differences?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ In the mobile version your name does not appear

Comment: @rpax that's only on android tho :p

Comment: I see what @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ see

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know... it's weird - but hey: that's what I get for having an awkward username ;P

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Um, how is this a duplicate? These two questions seem to be requesting completely different things.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen the duplicate is asking for the ability to expand the auto complete to everyone who can be notified, which includes "Anyone who edited the post", and more. Doing it will also fully cover the request here, which is only for editors. The unicode part here is not relevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Ah, sorry, I did miss the "editors" part in this request. You're right, this request does seem to be a subset of the one you marked this as a dupe of. Whether that actually makes it a duplicate is, I suppose, debatable. Presumably, the OP was hoping that this specific request might get implemented even if the more general one was declined (as it, indeed, currently is), since pinging users with non-ASCII names without auto-completion can be particularly difficult (especially if you can't easily copy-paste them, e.g. because you rely on keyboard navigation for accessibility).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen good point about the "specific request implemented even if general request declined", though thinking about it, it's also very similar to [this new request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278921/add-auto-completion-for-username-in-comments-when-typing). What do you think?