# Does tagging notify the users about them?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tell the user who will be notified of a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment)

As everyone can see, StackExchange has made a minor edit by suggesting users while tagging. The thing I want to know is whether the user tagged in the post is notified of this or not. This can be helpful if someone wants to target a user while asking a question.

Comment: Tagging doesn't have anything to do with users. Do you mean @-addressing other users in a comment? And you want to know whether the user you're addressing will be notified of your comment?

Answer (score 2):

There has never been and never will be a feature to "bug" certain users when you ask questions.

If they've listed their email and have welcomed unsolicited emails, then it is ok to contact them. If they've posted their twitter link, tweeting a post of yours their way would be acceptable (once in a while). Again, this depends on the user and YMMV.

Most users that you wish to target check your post anyway. If they've not answered, it's possibly because the other answers already answer the question or that they don't have the time to spend on your question. Either way, I don't think a mechanism to "alert" them would be well received.

Comment: I am not comparing it to them. They can refine this functionality. Say if a question hasn't got a good answer for two days, one can use this feature. IMO, refining a feature is the all or main task. It makes the feature suitable for different requirements.

Comment: That is why they have the bounty system in place :) Please read the  [faq#bounty] on bounties.

Comment: I have used the bounty myself but targeting bounty sometimes isn't enough. But maybe the SO team realized that adding this feature has more downfall than advantages. Anyway thanks yoda.