# How can we provide feedback when improving suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, improve-edit

Sometimes I notice the same users repeatedly making suggested edits, with some kind of general pattern of issues - they're generally fixing real problems, but also making erroneous changes of some kind in the process. I generally "improve" the suggested edit, and try to decide whether the helpfulness (finding a problem) or the unhelpfulness (messing things up) is more significant. And of course, sometimes they just have to be rejected outright.

As long as I'm putting in that effort, I'd like to be able to let these users know about the problems with their suggestions. I know that if I mark it as helpful, if they really wanted to, they could look at the edit history and see how I improved it. But that's unlikely to begin with, and the ones where it'd really be good for them to see that are the ones I did not mark as helpful. Is there anything I can do besides just trying to talk to them in chat, which feels uncomfortably like public shaming? Should I switch to rejecting the edits with custom comments? I'm hesitant to do that when I see that another reviewer has carelessly voted to approve a bad edit, or when the edit should really be improved and marked as helpful.

Comment: How about like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498015/unity-ios-development-build-always-yields-non-arc-xcode-project#comment20237889_14498015)?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Given that I don't get the autocomplete popup on for the users who suggested edits, I'm not sure that actually works.

Comment: ACK! I mixed you up with another user. My bad! That does work, though; just no autocomplete. I got my tabs mixed up and thought you were the user that I was notifying in that post.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ah, great. From the post about notifiaction: "Tab name completion can be used... It also does not work for editors." And it sounds like the [lack of completion for this "rare use case" is deliberate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment/106733#comment-274143). In any case, this isn't exactly a full solution, because it only works when you marked the edit as helpful. Otherwise, the user never edited the question and can't be @-notified.