# Verify @user in comment was entered correctly

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies, autocomplete

Is there some way to verify if an @user tag in a comment was correctly entered (meaning that the user was appropriately notified)?

I am aware of the [auto-complete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please) feature that is present when commenting and that is what I tend to use just to avoid any concern that I mistyped a user's name when commenting.

I am also aware of this question about [telling the user who will be notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment) which would probably have been good enough for my purposes as well if it had been implemented.

From these two issues I am led to assume that we are supposed to use the auto-complete, but there is no way to verify after the fact if we actually notified who we thought we notified--a real user, the right user or no one at all as the @users are not linked in the comment. While it may seem that I have answered my own question I don't like to rely on my assumptions and I couldn't find any confirmation of how it is all supposed to work "officially".

Comment: And take away the amusement I derive from the various ways people misspell my name?!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I second that; once I get my name back on April 3.

Comment: @MartjinPeters Hmm...

Comment: @MartijnPieters (see above comment `;)`)

Comment: @Doorknob: You forgot to insert extra 'n' and 'j' characters! :-)

Comment: @Mar​tein, some typos don't stop the notification ;-)

Comment: @Argan: I am fully aware of what works! :-P